# Python sort with key=lambda gets TypeError

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, lambda

I am trying to sort a list of objects in Python 3.4 based on the value of the data attribute of each object. If I use

```
db[count].sort(key=lambda a: a.data)
```

everything works fine. However, I want the sort to be case insensitive so I use

```
db[count].sort(key=lambda a: a.data.lower)
```

but then I get

> db[count].sort(key=lambda a: a.data.lower)
>   TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() < builtin_function_or_method()

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to *call* `lower()` from your `lambda`.

Comment: Sorry sussed it. I needed db[count].sort(key=lambda a: a.data.lower())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key` has to be a callable that returns a value to be sorted. In your case it returns another callable `a.data.lower`. You need to call `lower` in order to get the value, so the correct form is:

```
db[count].sort(key=lambda a: a.data.lower())
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a reference to the `lower` method instead of calling it.

Try this:

```
db[count].sort(key=lambda a: a.data.lower())
```